# Boot problems after upgrading to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, boot, laptop, fglrx, ati

After updating from Maverick to Natty (complete reinstalling, without saving personal information), i had issues with booting.

I'll try to describe:
First reboot after installation of Natty, system boot normally, had no issues, works good. But when i power off my laptop, and power on it again, i have boot problems. System seems to start, ubuntu violet colors screen, then blinking cursor in top left, and then it hangs(dont know sure if it hangs), but screen is completely black, and i had to hard reset the laptop. After first boot failing, and rebooting, every time i reboot - it shows me GRUB menu (i dont initiate it, i run itself)

Sometimes i had to reboot my laptop for 3 or more times, sometimes 10 times. 
Sometimes it starts normal on first boot.

Don't know what's this, after system start, after rebooting several times, it shows no errors or kind of that.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

**In Maverick i had no issues starting the OS.**

Hardware:

- HP g62-a16er with i3 processor
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
- Switchable-graphics technology (maybe this causes this issues??)

PS Sorry for my english!

Comment: try entering into  low graphics mode an remove the ati drivers if you have installed them. sudo apt-get remove fglrx, then select recover graphics (or someting by that name)

Comment: I haven't installed that driver. It appeared after clean installation of newer version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.
There are two steps.

1) Install the latest ATI Catalyst 11.4 driver. (AMD said that they have solved problems with switchable graphics and drivers problem, and this is BIG PRESENT for Linux users.)

2) Disable the radeon kernel module, and let the video driver handle all work with the video card.

```
echo "blacklist radeon" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf
update-initramfs -u
```

These two steps helped me fix my boot problems. It also sped up boot time by 2-3 times. Also it enables me to work with switchable graphics on notebooks(AT LAST!). And many other benefits! So for now, I am happy.